# Combo Box selected value validating

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to validate combo box values in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296801/how-to-validate-combo-box-values-in-c-sharp)

I have 6 combo boxes in c# form that all fill from database from same column.
i-e for making student result combo boxes fill subject names.
now I want is how to delete Subject name from 2nd combo box if the Subject is already selected in the previous combo box.

Comment: you might want to specify Winforms or asp.net as well

Comment: Are you using the same datasource binded to the 6 comboboxes?

Comment: i try to upload form image as well but stack over flow not allow me because of no rank

Comment: How are you hooking the database values up to a combobox? Are you using a `BindingSource` or are you manipulating the control's `Items` property? If you're using a `BindingSource`, are you using a single one for all of them?

Comment: Do you want a solution in C#, which will require postback or AJAX on each selection, or a Javascript solution which would be done client-side?

Comment: Yes i want the solution in c#

Comment: tobias89 i am using BindingSource to fill the combobox

Comment: is there any solution yesterday?